# Problem with getting id of the rails object when using jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement a simple search option in Rails with additional help of jQuery.The idea is that there is a table of transactions and user can search for:

1. Highest to Lowest and vice versa
2. Newest and Oldest
3. Active, Waiting and Rejected transactions(each transaction has one of these properties)

When I go to '/transactions'(index action) I see all of the transactions with each column value(6 out of 6).
However, after I click one of the search options I get missing values for column 'ID' and 'Delete'(4 out of 6).
In both cases I grab the id of single transaction, so probably it turns out to be nil, hence the missing values.
My question is: How Can I display the value in 'ID' and 'Delete' column for every transactions?
Here is my view for index.html.erb:

```
<%= provide(:title, "Transactions") %>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-2 text-center">
    <% if @search_transactions %>
      <div class="row" id="my_filter" >

        <%= form_tag transactions_path, remote: true, method: :get do %>

          <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= label_tag :date, "Highest" %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :value, "Highest", params[:value]%>

            <%= label_tag :date, "Lowest" %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :value, "Lowest", params[:value] %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= label_tag :date, "Newest" %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :date, "Newest", params[:date] %>

            <%= label_tag :date, "Oldest" %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :date, "Oldest", params[:date] %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3">
            
            <%= label_tag :status, "Active" %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :status, "active", params[:status] %>

            <%= label_tag :status, "Rejected" %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :status, "rejected", params[:status] %>

            <%= label_tag :status, "Waiting" %>
            <%= radio_button_tag :status, "waiting", params[:status] %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3">
            <%= submit_tag "Filter", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
          </div>

        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <table class="table table-responsive">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">ID</th>
              <th scope="col">Issuer</th>
              <th scope="col">Value</th>
              <th scope="col">Status</th>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Delete</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <%= render partial: 'search_transaction', collection: @search_transactions %>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <% else %>
        <h1>Users have not made any transactions yet!<h1>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is _search_transaction.html.erb partial:

```
<tr class="table-danger">
  <td><%= search_transaction.id %></td>
  <td><%= User.find(search_transaction.user_id).name %></td>
  <td><%= search_transaction.value %></td>
  <td><%= status(search_transaction) %></td>
  <td><%= pretty_date(search_transaction) %></td>
  <td><%= link_to "Delete", transaction_path(search_transaction.id), 
                                        method: :delete, 
                                        data: {confirm: "Are you sure" } %></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my index.js.erb:

```
$(':submit').click(function(){
  $('table tbody').html('<%= j render @search_transactions %>');
});
```

And TransactionsController(only index action):

```
class TransactionsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search_transactions = Transaction.all
    @search_transactions = @search_transactions.filter_by_value(params[:value]) if 
                           params[:value].present?
    @search_transactions = @search_transactions.filter_by_date(params[:date]) if 
                           params[:date].present?
    @search_transactions = @search_transactions.filter_by_status(params[:status]) if 
                           params[:status].present?
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
      format.html
    end
  end 

end
```

Also, I don't know why I have to click two times on the submit in order to see the changes on the page.
I would appreciate any help or advice.
Thanks in advance,
Lukas